# How to send a message via sockets from a controller?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a server. There are websockets here

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const cors = {
    origin: '*'
}


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {cors});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log('CONNECTION!!!!');

  socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
  })
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App started on port ${PORT}`);
})

module.exports = {
  io
}
```

And I have controller.
After deleting or creating a task, I have to send a message to all clients so that they update their lists.

```
const { io } = require('../index');

module.exports.createUserTask = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {body, tokenPayload: {userId}} = req;
        const task = await Task.create({...body, 
                                        authorId: userId});
                                        
        io.emit('SOCKET_REFRESH_TASK_LIST');
        res.status(201).send({data: task});
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

The following error comes to the client.

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Move `io` to a separate file.  Your `./app` runs first, then all of the code of `index.js` (because you imported it first). You have a circular import

Comment: @Konrad, Thanks a lot! It worked